# What is meant by a linear SDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am sure this is a ridiculous question, but I can't seem to find a definition. I know the definition of linear ODE or PDE just by saying that the differential operator should be linear, but how does one define a linear SDE?

---

Is the following correct? 
The SDE (driven by Brownian motion) $$dX_t=\mu(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}t+\sigma(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}B_t$$

is called linear if for all $t$, $x\mapsto \mu(t,x)$ and $x\mapsto\sigma(t,x)$ are linear functions.

---

And I assume we can extend this definition to path-dependent coefficients?

Comment: I have my own definition that $df = f dt + f dW$ but it be interesting to know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$dX_t=(a(t)X_t+b(t))dt+(c(t)X(t)+d(t))dW_t$

Comment: So no coefficents dependent on $W_t$? +1 pending :).

Comment: @Chinny84 Nothing was said about $a(t),b(t),c(t),d(t)$, they could be random functions of time. But you should be sure that they are adapted in the right way that the stochastic integral makes sense.